# how to add dynamic text before and after of post title

Tags: title, theme-twenty-twenty-one

In twenty twenty one theme how to add dynamic text before and after of post title. I want to add “Premium” word before title and “today” word after the title. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You should create a child theme and then edit the file where you want the dynamic text to appear. So if you want to show the text on single blog pages, you'll simply use the `single.php` file in your child theme.

More on WordPress child themes here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/